# Unit test inside a Module in yii2

Tags: php, unit-testing, module, yii2, codeception

How can i perform unit test inside a module. here's my project structure [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) is a good example of solution.

Add `include` section to [project level codeception.yml](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/codeception.yml) file:

```
include:
    - modules/api
    - modules/dtr
```

`Include` setting is documented at https://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#One-Runner-for-Multiple-Applications

You need codeception.yml file in modules/dtr directory, it lools like normal standalone codeception.yaml file.

- `codecept run` command would run project level tests and tests of included modules.
- `codecept run modules/dtr/tests/unit/` executes all unit tests of that module.
- `codecept run modules/dtr/tests/unit/models/FirstTest.php` executes specific test

If you don't want to have a top level codeception.yml file, you can specify path to module directory (you need codeception.yml file there anyway).

- `codecept run -c modules/dtr` executes all tests
- `codecept run -c modules/dtr tests/unit/models/FirstTest.php` executes specific test
- but it is more convenient to use name filter - `codecept run -c modules/dtr  :FirstTest`

`-c` parameter is documented at https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Running-from-different-folders

Comment: Thankyou very much for the specific answer. I'll try this :)